# systemd: how do I create/destroy instances dynamically when config files appear/disappear?

Tags: systemd

I want to have a service with several instances, each of which has a configuration file; when configuration files appear and disappear, I want the corresponding instance to be created and die, respectively, and in particular have the running processes corresponding to the removed units be killed.

I can get them to start the first time, but they do not stop when configuration files change.

I tried modelling this after what OpenVPN does:

In `/etc/systemd/system/letters.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Letters service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
WorkingDirectory=/var/tmp/letters

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In `/etc/systemd/system/letters@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Letters for %i
PartOf=letters.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=letters.service
Before=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=false
WorkingDirectory=/var/tmp/letters
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/letter --daemon --pidfile /run/letters/%i.pid
PIDFile=/run/letters/%i.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In `/etc/systemd/system-generators/letters`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>> /tmp/opg2
set -eux
GENDIR="$1"
WANTDIR="$1/letters.service.wants"
SERVICEFILE="/lib/systemd/system/letters@.service"
CONFIG_DIR=/var/letters/
mkdir -p "$WANTDIR"
for CONFIG in `cd $CONFIG_DIR; ls *.conf 2> /dev/null`; do
  NAME=${CONFIG%%.conf}
  ln -s "$SERVICEFILE" "$WANTDIR/letters@$NAME.service"
done
exit 0
```

Now for the fun:

```
# touch /var/letters/aleph.conf /var/letters/e.conf /var/letters/zeta.conf

# systemctl enable letters.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/letters.service → /etc/systemd/system/letters.service.

# ls -l /run/systemd/generator/letters.service.wants/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar 17 05:47 letters@aleph.service -> /lib/systemd/system/letters@.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar 17 05:47 letters@e.service -> /lib/systemd/system/letters@.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar 17 05:47 letters@zeta.service -> /lib/systemd/system/letters@.service

# systemctl start letters.service
# ps ax | grep letter
14118 ?        S      0:00 /usr/local/bin/letter --daemon --pidfile /run/letters/aleph.pid
14125 ?        S      0:00 /usr/local/bin/letter --daemon --pidfile /run/letters/zeta.pid
14126 ?        S      0:00 /usr/local/bin/letter --daemon --pidfile /run/letters/e.pid
```

So far so good.

Now:

```
# touch /var/letters/tcha.conf
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start letters.service
```

And happily, a fourth process appeared.

**but now the trouble starts**

If I `rm /var/letters/aleph.conf; systemctl daemon-reload`, I expect the aleph process to die. **It does not!** I don't want to have to restart the service, because I don't want to kill the processes that are not affected by the configuration change.

What am I doing wrong? For that matter, is this even the right approach? Nothing stands out in `journalctl -xe`, and I don't know how to proceed about debugging this.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in your generator looks for running services corresponding to nonexistent files. You'll need to write this.

Comment: I thought the generator was not supposed to do anything of the sort. The man page says:  ·   Generators should only be used to generate unit files, not any other kind of configuration. Due to the lifecycle logic mentioned above, generators are not a good fit to generate dynamic
           configuration for other services. If you need to generate dynamic configuration for other services, do so in normal services you order before the service in question.

Comment: I realize, of course, that I can write a shell script to kill the instances that should no longer be running, but that's not the point!

Comment: Did you look at what your generator leaves after being run? It looks that your generator creates links for files that exist, but your generator doesn't remove links for files that vanished.